# mod_vhost_alias and VirtualDocumentRoot: How to add penultimate and last part?

Tags: apache2, alias, virtualhost, mod-vhost-alias

How to obtain a directory name consisting of two last parts of the domain name. Or use a dot?

For example, I have a domain **any.ms** and I would like the dynamic domains **foo.any.ms** and domain **bar.any.ms** also pointing to the **/var/www/dev/any.ms/public** directory. Or domain **any.lorem.ipsum.ms** to point to the directory **/var/www/dev/ipsum.ms/public**.

My *ms.conf* for now (not working, apache won't start):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *.ms
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/dev/%-2%.%-1/public
    UseCanonicalName Off
    <Directory "/var/www/dev">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I use the documentation http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html but I can not insert dots writing **/%-2.%-1/**, **/%-2%.%-1/**, **/%-2\.%-1/**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just found a solution:

> If you want to include the . (dot) character in a VirtualDocumentRoot directive, but it crashes with a % directive, you can work around the problem in the following way:
>
> VirtualDocumentRoot /usr/local/apache/vhosts/%2.0.%3.0

Working solution:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *.ms
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/dev/%-2.0.%-1.0/public
    UseCanonicalName Off
    <Directory "/var/www/dev">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, helped me too. But escaping the dot also works for me. E. g. `VirtualDocumentRoot "/var/www/dev/%1\.example.com"`